# Modify error bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am trying to do two things with the following graph
1 - Make capped error bar
2 - Bold the error bars

[image]

This is the set of code I used

```
data$rotation[data$Rot.trt %in% c("C2", "S2")]<-"TwoYear"
data$rotation[data$Rot.trt %in% c("C3", "S3", "O3")]<-"ThreeYear"
data$rotation[data$Rot.trt %in% c("C4", "S4", "O4", "A4")]<-"FourYear"


ggplot(data, aes(x=Rot.Herb.label, y=kg.ha, fill=Crop))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    facet_grid(~rotation, scales = "free_x", space="free_x")+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")+
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())+
    ggtitle("Weed biomass by plot")+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size=30, face="bold", vjust=2))+
    xlab("Treatment (L = Low herbicide regime, C = Conventional herbicide regime)")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, angle = 90, hjust = 1),axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))+
    ylab("Weed dry weight (kg/ha)")+
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16))
```

As referred to [this question](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/), I tried to add this part before the `geom_boxplot` line but it didn't help.

```
geom_bar(width= .1, position="dodge", color="black", stat="identity")+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=kg.ha-ci, ymax=kg.ha+ci),
              width=.2,                    
　            position=position_dodge(.9))
```

Here is what I have reached so far. 
[image]

And here is the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn6gwshpawo9cad/DataJul.csv?dl=0)

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  69 variables:
 $ Date            : Factor w/ 10 levels "10-Sep-14","12-Sep-14",..: 10 10 10 10 10 10 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Plot            : int  11 11 13 13 18 18 23 23 24 24 ...
 $ Rep             : Factor w/ 4 levels "1rep","2rep",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Side            : Factor w/ 2 levels "E","W": 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ Crop            : Factor w/ 4 levels "alfalfa","corn",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Rot             : Factor w/ 3 levels "2rot","3rot",..: 2 2 1 1 3 3 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ Rot.Herb        : Factor w/ 18 levels "A4conv","A4low",..: 5 6 4 3 8 7 5 6 4 3 ...
 $ Rot.trt         : Factor w/ 9 levels "A4","C2","C3",..: 3 3 2 2 4 4 3 3 2 2 ...
 $ Herb.trt        : Factor w/ 2 levels "conv","low": 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ DIGSANo         : int  0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DIGSAWt         : num  0 0 0 0 1.3 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SETFANo         : int  1 3 1 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 ...
 $ SETFAWt         : num  0.1 61 1.5 0 14 0 0 4.1 0 0 ...
 $ SETLUNo         : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SETLUWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PANCANo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PANCAWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ECHCGNo         : int  0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ECHCGWt         : num  0 0 0 0 21.7 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ERBVINo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ERBVIWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CYPESNo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CYPESWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AMATANo         : int  0 2 8 4 2 1 1 0 1 3 ...
 $ AMATAWt         : num  0 25.5 8.3 0.1 1.2 0 0 0 0.03 1.57 ...
 $ CHEALNo         : int  6 44 0 0 0 0 0 15 2 0 ...
 $ CHEALWt         : num  0.1 208.1 0 0 0 ...
 $ SOLPTNo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 11 1 3 18 4 ...
 $ SOLPTWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0.4 0.08 0.3 5.81 0.17 ...
 $ PHYSUNo         : int  0 5 2 6 2 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PHYSUWt         : num  0 2.1 13.9 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ POLCCNo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ POLCCWt         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ POLPYNo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ POLPYWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ABUTHNo         : int  4 0 2 0 6 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ ABUTHWt         : num  0.2 0 0.1 0 3.1 0 0.07 0 0 0 ...
 $ TAROFNo         : int  6 4 0 21 6 3 6 7 17 33 ...
 $ TAROFWt         : num  0.1 0 0 0 0.1 0 0.07 0.23 0.18 0.51 ...
 $ EPHHTNo         : int  0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 5 0 ...
 $ EPHHTWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0.13 0 ...
 $ CIRARNo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CIRARWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SONARNo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ SONARWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0 ...
 $ MORALNo         : int  0 5 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ MORALWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ OXASTNo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ OXASTWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ POLLANo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ POLLAWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ASCSYNo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ASCSYWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ POLAVNo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ POLAVWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PLAMANo         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PLAMAWt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ UnknowndicotNo  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ UnknowndicotWt  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ UnknownmonocotNo: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ UnknownmonocotWt: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TOTALNo         : int  17 63 13 32 29 17 9 27 44 40 ...
 $ TOTALWt         : num  0.5 296.7 23.8 0.1 41.7 ...
 $ samplearea.m.2. : num  18.5 18.5 18.5 18.5 18.5 ...
 $ g.m.2           : num  0.03 16.01 1.28 0.01 2.25 ...
 $ kg.ha           : num  0.27 160.1 12.84 0.05 22.5 ...
 $ lb.acre         : num  0.24 142.97 11.47 0.05 20.09 ...
 $ rotation        : chr  "Three Year" "Three Year" "Two Year" "Two Year" ...
 $ Rot.Herb.label  : Factor w/ 8 levels "Alfalfa C","Alfalfa L",..: 3 4 4 3 4 3 3 4 4 3 ...
```